# Using log4j2 and log4j at the same time in Spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

I've a Spring Boot Applications that uses third-party library. That library uses `log4j` as its logger. When there is no `log4j` in classpath, my application fails to start because that third-party library throws an exception pointing to missing `log4j`. To handle this, I decided to use `log4j2` instead of Spring's default `logback`. To do so, I put the following in `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Additionally, to allow for that thrid-party library to work, I also added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Now,the third-party library works, however, everything is logged twice. How do I to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding the log4j dependency to your project, add the **log4j 1.x bridge** to your project, which will make sure your library that depends on log4j actually works with Log4j2 without knowing it.

So, make sure to **remove the old log4j 1.2** dependency and add this one instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If that didn't work then you are either still getting the log4j dependency some other way or have misconfigured your logging configuration so that events are logged twice - that can happen if you do not have your additivity settings correct.